# How do the action of elgg in out of plugins

Tags: php, plugins, action, elgg

I'm new to elgg, i want to create a action of the submit in out of the plugins,the current page is

In code

```
  <input type="submit" name="submit" action="<?php echo  site_url ?>/action/datacheck" />
```

the output is below

```
  http://localhost/sample.com/testplugins/action/datacheck.php
```

i need to action out of the plugins like

```
  http://localhost/sample.com/action/datacheck.php
```

also i give the url in directly

but was not working,how can i give the url

please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused. Do you mean to ask how to construct an Elgg form properly or a special use case in which there is an exotic need to create the action link in such a manner?

If you want to create an action at your preferred at address, try creating a page handler for `'action'` identifier and add a case for `'datacheck'` segment.